# Configure error , library not found on OS X

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I would like to compile the ffmpeg and I receive this error:

`ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found`

I copied the library to `/usr/...` and also to `/usr/local/...`

I also have this in my script: `CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH -I/usr/local/include"`

Do you have any more hint why does this happen?

Comment: Save yourself a lot of grief and just install the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) version: `brew install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR , but the thing is that I would like to build ffmpeg for the iOS. This way I cannot really use homebrew.

Comment: Ah, OK, that wasn't clear from the question. Surely there must be pre-built libraries out there for iOS though ? (I don't know, because I'm not an iOS developer - just guessing...)

Comment: There is one, but not with mp3 support, I am trying to rebuild it.

Comment: Oh well - good luck with that!